# while using useeffect when I get the data I print it but it not setting the value when I am using usestate in the useeffect

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-hooks

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

//useparam url theke niye nei

export default function MoviePage() {
  const [currentMovie, setcurrentMovie] = useState();
  const { id } = useParams();
  //data dibo id diye ekhon data gulo nibo

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/MoviePage", {
          id: id,
        });
        console.log(response.data);
        setcurrentMovie(response.data.rows);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); // Added id to the dependency array

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentMovie);
  }, [currentMovie]);


  return (
    <div></div>

    );
}
```

I am building a React application using create-react-app, and I am trying to fetch data from an API using the axios library. The API is returning the data as expected(I know cz I am printing it), but when I try to set the state using setcurrentMovie(response.data.rows), the state is not being updated. I have verified that the API response is correct and that the setcurrentMovie function is being called with the correct data. However, the state remains undefined.

Comment: don't use create-react-app

Comment: I guess that `response.data.rows` is `undefined`

Comment: no when I am doing console.log(response.data.rows) , its a success 
but when I am using setcurrentMovie and doing console.log(currentMovie) its undefined then

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury what I should use? vite? can you tell me if I shift to vite will it give me correct input?

Comment: vite is defo a good option. But if you ask me I would go with next.js. Development to production is like a breeze. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of the result of this log - `console.log(response.data);`

Comment: can you tell me if I could solve this problem without shifting  @na

Comment: @HILLOLCHAKMAPollux-379 Just a recommendation to avoid managing an extra state just for an API call: use a server state management library like react-query https://medium.com/leniolabs/what-is-react-query-74d936f0ef94.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not necessary to do with the `useEffect` with dependency `currentMovie`

When you are setting the state here

```js
console.log(response.data);
setcurrentMovie(response.data.rows);
```

There is a chance that `.rows` is undefined so your 2nd `useEffect` does not trigger at all

What I suggest doing is as a quick test is

```js
export default function MoviePage() {
  const [currentMovie, setcurrentMovie] = useState();

  const { id } = useParams();
  //data dibo id diye ekhon data gulo nibo

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/MoviePage", {
          id: id,
        });
         // Set the state just with the response data 
        setcurrentMovie(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); // Added id to the dependency array

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentMovie);

// Not a good idea to put in an `object` 
// as an dependency it can cause a lot of re-renders
  }, [currentMovie]);


  return (
// Bad code but just to test 
    <div>{currentMovie ? JSON.stringify(currentMovie) : 'No data'}</div>

    );
}
```

There is possibility that this might be a backend issue since I am seeing here you are using `localhost`.